# "Eclipse-BundleShape: dir" header is not working and still the plugins are exported as JAR's

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, bundle, rcp

I'm having Eclipse Indigo (3.7) and I have the BundleShape header being set in the MANIFEST.MF of my plugin.

```
Eclipse-BundleShape: dir
```

If I export the product it is still exporting the plugin as JAR and not as a directory.

**NOTE :** My project is a Plugin based project.

Anything I'm missing ??

Suggestions are welcomed..!

Answer (score 2):

Is your product feature based? If so, you can set the "Unpack the plug-in archive after the installation" option in your feature.

- open your feature.xml file
- switch to the "Included Plug-ins" tab
- select the plugin which should be in directory instead of jar form
- check "Unpack the plug-in archive after the installation" on the right side

@ EclipseSource it says: "the feature will always win. If the feature isn’t available or the unpack attribute isn’t specified, the bundle will be consulted for its shape."
http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2009/01/20/tip-eclipse-bundleshape/
So the reason why the BundleShape header is ignored is probably the `unpack="false"` attribute in your feature.xml.

Comment: Flavi :  My product is plugin based project and not feature based. 
            So, what would be the issue in this scenario ??

Comment: Just did a test and it worked using Eclipse 4.5.1. If you only have a few own plugins, you could try to download the latest Eclipse and create a new workspace, export from there. On the otherhand you could try to use a feature based product.

Comment: That will be fine... but I'm just curious to know why it fails in my case (with my version of eclipse). Or what could be the possible reasons for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have just had a problem with this directive. In one project it worked as expected, in another a jar was always produced and not a folder.

In the first project the directive was right at the end of the MANIFEST file, in the second it was near the top. I moved the `Bundle-Shape: dir` directive to the end of the file and the problem appears to have been solved.